# C++ string to LLVM IR

Tags: c++11, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

I would like to take a string representation of a C++ lambda function like this:

```
string fun = "[](int x) { return x + 5;}";
string llvm_ir = clang.get_llvm_ir(fun);  // does something like this exist?
```

and convert it to LLVM IR using Clang from within C++.  Is there a way to do this directly using Clang's internal API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no stable, officially supported API to do this. The [Clang C API](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Index_8h_source.html) provides front-end level information (source-code level). Neither does Clang tooling provide this.

You do have good options though. The easiest is to just invoke the Clang front-end as a subprocess `clang -cc1 -emit-llvm ...<other options>`. This will produce a LLVM IR file which you can then read. It's actually fairly common practice in compilers - the Clang driver itself does this - it invokes the frontend and a bunch of other tools (like the linker), depending on the specific compilation task.

Alternatively, if you feel you must have a programmatic API for this, you can dig in the code of the Clang front-end (the `-cc1` invocation mentioned above) to see how it accomplishes it, and collect bits and pieces of code. Be prepared to write a huge amount of scaffolding, though, because these APIs were not designed to be used externally.

To reiterate, it *is* possible using internal APIs, but there's no easy or recommended way following this path.